# Remove values based on specific relation to previous value in same column

Tags: r

I have daily stock return data for several companies and need to remove those values, which have a specific relation to the previous (= the day before) return value.
In a mathematical formula it looks something like that:(1+r)*(1+e)-1<= 50%, where r is the return on the current day and e the return on the previous day, and at least either r or e being greater than 100%.
The data frame DF looks like that.

```
Date          A     B     C     D
01.01.2015    0.15  0.17  0.70  0.65
02.01.2015    1.01  0.75  0.01  -0.18
01.02.2015    -0.50  0.64  1.20  0.1
06.02.2015    0.12  0.54  0.13  1.50
01.03.2016    0.45  0.54  1.89  0.56
```

Afte apllying this filter DF should look like this.

```
Date          A     B     C     D
01.01.2015    0.15  0.17  0.70  0.65
02.01.2015    1.01  0.75  0.01  -0.18
01.02.2015    NA    0.64  1.20  0.1
06.02.2015    0.12  0.54  0.13  1.50
01.03.2016    0.45  0.54  1.89  0.56
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you explain how you did come from the input to the output.
The only diff I recognise is at 1.2.2015 / A.
And what's the difference to 1.2.2015 / B.

Comment: 1.2.2015 A: (1+(-0.5)*(1+1.01) -1 = 0.005 ergo < 50% (0.5) and e in this case is larger than 100% (1.0).
1.2.2015 B: I don't see a case, where this needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

check_fn <- function(Z){
  ifelse(((lag(Z, n=1) > 1 | Z >1) & ((1+lag(Z, n=1))*(1+Z) <= 1.5)), NA, Z)
}

Y <- X %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(2:5), check_fn)

Y[1, 2:5] <- X[1, 2:5]

Y
```

... which generates:

```
        Date    A    B    C     D
1 01.01.2015 0.15 0.17 0.70  0.65
2 02.01.2015 1.01 0.75 0.01 -0.18
3 01.02.2015   NA 0.64 1.20  0.10
4 06.02.2015 0.12 0.54 0.13  1.50
5 01.03.2016 0.45 0.54 1.89  0.56
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misread some of your post. I have corrected it so it matches your expected output.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat = dat[ , lapply(.SD, relationship), .SDcols = c("A", "B", "C", "D")]

relationship = function(x){
  return(ifelse(((1 + x)*(1 + shift(x)) - 1) < .5 & !is.na(shift(x)) & (x > 1 | shift(x) > 1), NA, x))
}

> dat[ , lapply(.SD, relationship), .SDcols = c("A", "B", "C", "D")]
      A    B    C     D
1: 0.15 0.17 0.70  0.65
2: 1.01 0.75 0.01 -0.18
3:   NA 0.64 1.20  0.10
4: 0.12 0.54 0.13  1.50
5: 0.45 0.54 1.89  0.56
```

You can cbind the dates back onto the data.table

I should add incase there are many more columns that this needs to be done on and you don't want to write them all out you could do something like this.

```
Dates = dat$Date
dat[ , "Date" := NULL]
dat = dat[ , lapply(.SD, relationship)]
```

That will apply the function to every column in the data.table.

Comment: R gives me an error, that it can't find "test" in the relationship function.

Answer (score 0):

There might for shure be a more elegang solution.

```
> M=matrix(c(0.15,0.17,0.70,0.65,1.01,0.75,0.01,-0.18,-0.50,0.64,1.20,0.1,0.12,0.54,0.13,1.50,0.45,0.54,1.89,0.56),nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)
> M
      [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  0.15 0.17 0.70  0.65
[2,]  1.01 0.75 0.01 -0.18
[3,] -0.50 0.64 1.20  0.10
[4,]  0.12 0.54 0.13  1.50
[5,]  0.45 0.54 1.89  0.56
> ifelse(rbind(c(T,T,T,T), !(((M[2:5,]>1)|(M[1:4,]>1))&(((1+M[2:5,])*(1+M[1:4,])-1)<.5))), M, NA)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
[1,] 0.15 0.17 0.70  0.65
[2,] 1.01 0.75 0.01 -0.18
[3,]   NA 0.64 1.20  0.10
[4,] 0.12 0.54 0.13  1.50
[5,] 0.45 0.54 1.89  0.56
```